# Downloading xls of Tabulator table via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabulator

As per http://tabulator.info/examples/4.6#download
There is an option to download the table as xlsx:

```
//trigger download of data.xlsx file
document.getElementById("download-xlsx").addEventListener("click", function(){
    table.download("xlsx", "data.xlsx", {sheetName:"My Data"});
});
```

I am trying to write this in jQuery (as in http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/jquery)

```
    $("#download-xlsx").click(function(){
        $("#ovdim_list").tabulator.download("xlsx", "data.xlsx", {sheetName:"My Data"});
    });
```

But it's not working...

Comment: Do you have the jQuery wrapper and SheetJS(for xlsx download) library installed?  Are there any errors in browser console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery syntax, the correct function call is:

```js
$("#download-xlsx").click(function(){
    $("#ovdim_list").tabulator("download", "xlsx", "data.xlsx", {sheetName:"My Data"});
});
```

When using the jQuery wrapper the function name goes in the first argument to the Tabulator function